# CocoaLibSpotify streaming_error: SP_ERROR_OTHER_PERMANENT

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoalibspotify-2.0

When playing any track from the app I get this terrifying error message after a while (which causes the track to stop playing until I restart the playTrack: method):

> Error Domain=com.spotify.CocoaLibSpotify.error Code=10 "General
>   permanent error" UserInfo=0xe833c90 {NSLocalizedDescription=General
>   permanent error}

This never happened before and I wonder what might have caused it? I'm lost here and It's hard to find anything concerning the subject. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved. Tried to set "seekToTrack" where I shouldn't have.